# export file with correct encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, file, httpresponse

I don't understand what is missing here.  I am trying to export a file in csv format with extended `ASCII` characters like `ÿ` or `ü` but all i get is � 
Do I need to specify something else in the response?

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

//ToCSV writes the string correctly
var bytes = encoding.GetBytes("write ÿ or ü please");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
//TextWriter tw = new TextWriter();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.csv", fileName));
Response.Charset = encoding.EncodingName;
Response.ContentType = "application/text";
Response.Output.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Are you sure the client is using the right encoding to display the output?

Comment: I assume that by "all I get is �" you mean that is what you see in the browser. Have you examined the headers that your browser is receiving?

Comment: This code works fine for me Google Chrome as UA.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe you should add `Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode` to get right output.

```
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var bytes = encoding.GetBytes("write ÿ or ü please");
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.csv", "filename"));
    Response.Charset = encoding.EncodingName;
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.Output.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

Comment: It was actually specifying the charset by  Response.Charset = encoding.BodyName;

Comment: `encoding.WebName` should be used here. BodyName gives incorrect value for some encodings. For example, "koi8-r" for "windows-1251" encoding.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately `Encoding.Unicode` didn't work, using `Windows-1252` worked :

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"filename.csv\"");
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
Response.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myDataLines));
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Java programmer, are you sure you need a `StreamReader`? I guess `StreamReader(stream)` may decode the bytes in a different charset. And, You've already got the bytes, maybe you could write the bytes to response directly.

Comment: Maybe there is, but I am not sure how to do that.  I will give it a try.